# How to hold off rendering until ajax call completes

Tags: svelte, svelte-store

I am refactoring a React app that loads the language labels from a json file on the server. The data is pulled from the server using an Ajax call, which updates a store that contains all the language labels. Here is some code illlustrating the problem.

**app.js**

```
<script>
import { storeLang, getLangLabels } from './store'

// get labels from server
getLangLabels()

// set language labels in a reactive variable
$: LABELS = $storeLang.labels
</script>

<div>
 <h2>{LABELS.title}</h2>
</div>
```

Here is how the store is setup. The ajax call updates the store with the labels.

**store.js**

```
import { writeable } from 'svelte/store'

export const storeLang = writeable({})

export const getLangLabels = () => {
  return fetch('lang.json').then( data => {
  storeLang.set(data);
})
}
```

However, when I run the application I do not have access to the LABELS variable yet, nor it is updated when the fetch call is resolved. Here is the error message.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'LABELS' before initialization
```

The way I solved this problem in React was to render the entire `<App />` only after the language labels where fetched from the server. I have not figured out a way to solve this using **Svelte**.

Please advise.

### Solution

Following @tehshrike recommendation, I setup the `getLang` as an async function and using an await block on the `App.svelte` component, which is the entry point of the app. This way, when the promise resolves after getting the language labels, the App renders (code abbreviated for illustration purposes).

**App.svelte**

```
<script>
import { getLang } from './lang/store.js';

let promise = getLang();
</script>

{#await promise}
  Loading language labels
{:then value}
  // we don't use the returned value because the labels are stored in 
  // the store and the subscribed components react accordingly
  <Header />
  <Sidebar />
  <Main />
{:catch}
  Error resolving promise
{/await}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put your promise into the store itself, instead of waiting for the promise to resolve before putting the value into the store, you can use an [await block](https://svelte.dev/examples#await-blocks) and reference `$storeLang.labels` without needing to set up a reactive declaration inside your component.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you give me a code example? I think I already have the api calls in the store. Unless you mean moving the api call to a store property, but I will still need a little more info on how exactly I would implement this.

Comment: I figured out what you meant in your recommendation. I will edit the question with the solution.